# How to get panel with title bar in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java Swing application development.

[image]

I am looking to place a panel inside the window with title bar like Advanced JTable Demo, GUI Components of below image. How can I add them to window in Netbeans?

Comment: Doesn't that demo come with its source code?

Comment: I google about Nimbus theme, I found this image not source code.

Comment: @DyapaSrikanth It seems like the SwingSet3 sources can be found here: http://java.net/projects/swingset3/sources/svn/show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a JPanel for your main panel that uses a BorderLayout. Then create a Title panel and add it to the NORTH or the main panel. Then create a second panel for all your other components and add it to the CENTER of the main panel.

In other words there is no component that does what you want, you need to create one.

Comment: just a pointer: actually, there is - both in the demo and another in SwingX :-)

Comment: @kleopatra, sorry, I see that must be a new component in JDK7 I'm still on JDK6.

Comment: sorry, was unclear: a component in the swingset3 demo code, not in jdk7 :-)